# Receiving touch events in NSView when cursor is outside of the view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In my application I need to respond to trackpad touch events (touchesBeganWithEvent / touchesMovedWithEvent / touchesEndedWithEvent) in a custom NSView, I have the code working properly. But I also need to do this when the cursor is outside of the view when the touch starts and NSView doesn't receive these events in this case.

One direction I was exploring is subclassing NSApplication and overriding sendEvent. But I am not sure how to dispatch the proper messages to my NSView. Just forwarding these events to the NSWindow via sendEvent doesn't seem to work.

Or is there a better way? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ensured that your NSView's window is the key window?

Comment: Yes. As I said, everything works as expected when the cursor is over the NSView. When I move it outside and then begin a new touch event, it doesn't work anymore.